# Core deposits forecasting in stress testing

Tags: risk-management, risk-models, banking-regulations, stress-testing, banking

I’m designing a stress test at a commercial bank. What are the advantages/disadvantages of forecasting core NMD deposits vs. total deposit balances?

Comment: The most obvious advantage is that you will need to be able to separate core NMDs for the Basel capital framework’s Pillar 2 used for Interest rate risk in the
banking book (IRRBB) or the current QIS study in Europe. Insofar, you may simply have to use core NMDs.